# Django handle optional url parameter

Tags: python, css, django, templates, url

I want url to have optional url parameter. Primary url is:

```
url(r'^(?P<letnik_id>[1-4])/(?P<classes_id>[A-G])/(?P<subject_id>[\w\-]+)$', views.subject, name="subject_id"),
```

but after subject id i want to be able to add optional parameter that is always a number:

```
url(r'^(?P<letnik_id>[1-4])/(?P<classes_id>[A-G])/(?P<subject_id>[\w\-]+)/(?P<digit>\d+)/$'', views.subject, name="subject_id_optional"),
```

Im not even sure if did that correctly, as i dont know how to set number for parameter. So after the parameter is passed i want the (template?) or maybe view to read the number (which is model's ID number) and add css class ) `.highlited-model {background-color: red;}` to that model.
How would i achieve this and how should i handle it in views or template, wherever it makes more sense?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just have two urls pointing to the same view, one with your optional parameter, and one without:

```
urls = [
    url(r'^(?P<letnik_id>[1-4])/(?P<classes_id>[A-G])/(?P<subject_id>[\w\-]+)/(?P<digit>\d+)/$', views.subject, name="subject_id_optional"),
    url(r'^(?P<letnik_id>[1-4])/(?P<classes_id>[A-G])/(?P<subject_id>[\w\-]+)$', views.subject, name="subject_id"),

]

def subject(request, optional_parameter=''):

    return render(
        request,
        "template.html",
        {
            "optional_parameter": optional_parameter
        }
    )
```

Then you can get the parameter in your template as you would any other variable passed into the context.

Comment: thanks! Can you jus tplease explain to me why is this line needed?  "optional_parameter='' "